# how do i replace some properties returned from database in sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

So i'm trying to replace fields on the data queried from the database in sails.

```
async.waterfall( [
    function getscores(callback) {
        Score.find({course : courseId}).paginate({page : 1 , limit: 10}).populate('course')
               .exec(function(err,data) {
                  callback(null,data);
        });
}
, function addUserInfo(result,callback) {

    for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
      result[i].user = User.findOne({id : result[i].user}).exec(function(err,data) {
          var temp = {
            "name" : data.name,
            "id" : data.id,
            "user_id" : data.user_id
          }
          return temp;
      });

    }
    res.json(messageGenerator(200, 'Sucecss', result));
}],function(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
);
```

the first function 'getScores' returns the scores array but each score property only has a user id. Now in addUserInfo function, i want to be able to add the user's name to the score property.

But the above code fails to return the users inside. the user property of score is empty. i believe the response is already sent before the program gets to add the user property ( due to asyncronousness of the database adapter).

Comment: I'm confused as to why you aren't calling `populate` with your User model aswell as the Course model. The issue you have is that `res.json` is getting called before the for loop has finished. I see you're using the async library; you could wrap it in an [async.each()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each)

Comment: the actual user model consists of sensitive information , so i would only like to add the name of the user

Comment: You can define the fields you'd like to populate using the 2nd param of the populate call with the `select` key, e.g. `.populate('course', { select: ['name', 'id' ] })`

Comment: Thanks. But it seems the select in populate is not working with sails-mysql.

Comment: That's a shame! There have been some issues with the `select` keyword bit I thought they'd been resolved. `sails-mysql-transactions` claims to have implemented the `select` keyword but their replacement of both waterline and sails-mysql concern me. Let me refactor your `addUserInfo` func and I'll drop it in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a brief comment chat, the following replacement for the `addUserInfo` function should help you achieve what you desire:

```
function addUserInfo(results,callback) {
  async.map(results, function(result, callback) {
    User.findOne({id : result.user}).exec(function(err, data) {
      callback(err, Object.assign(result, {
        "user": {
          "name" : data.name || null,
          "id" : data.id || null,
          "user_id" : data.user_id || null
        }
      }));
    });
  }, function(err, output) {
    return res.json(messageGenerator(200, "Success", output))
  });
}
```

Async map allows us to asynchronously iterate over results, allowing us to amend the `result` by supplying the `callback` with the new `result` as the second parameter. The Final function is our final callback, that gets provided with any `err`'s that have occured along the way and our new Array as `output`.